# Ejecutar script sin que termine cuando hay error en apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Tengo un código en apps script donde borro un evento en calendario con la siguiente instrucción

```
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Id@group.calendar.google.com")
.getEventSeriesById(IdParaBorrar).deleteEventSeries()
```

Funciona bien cuando el evento existe, pero cuando el evento(IdParaBorrar) no existe, el código se detiene.

No encuentro la manera de borrar el evento solo si es que existe y continúe sin marcar error.

¿Saben de qué manera puedo lograrlo?

Comment: Hola Fernando, ¿al final has solucionado el problema?

Comment: Fernando Tovar: Tu pregunta puede plantearse mejor, por ejemplo, indicando que has buscado y lo que has intentado. También podrías incluir un [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo suyo es hacerlo en dos partes. La primera para recuperar el `CalendarEventSeries`:

```
var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Id@group.calendar.google.com").getEventSeriesById(IdParaBorrar);
```

hacer la comprobación y luego el `deleteEventSeries()`.

Lo que no recuerdo muy bien es si te devuelve un nulo o tienes que verificar alguna propiedad como `getId()`.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Utilice tu opcion porque entendi la logica que me planteaste, gracias

Comment: Gracias Fernando

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

Una alternativa es usar [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch)

## Explicación

Google Apps Script está basado en JavaScript por lo que es posible usar muchas de las técnicas para el [control de flujo y manejo de errores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_de_flujo_y_manejo_de_errores).

Del enlace en la sección respuesta corta (formato de código es mío para destacar los comandos)

> La sentencia de `try` consiste un bloque `try` , esta contiene una o más instrucciones, y al menos una clausula `catch` o una `finally` , o bien ambas.

## Bibliografía adicional

- [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) (Página oficial, en inglés, de introducción al servicio)

Comment: Gracias Ruben, me parece buena la opcion pero los ejemplos que encontre en internet me revolvieron un poco, asi que utilice la otra opcion